# array object with empty field name

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node-red

In node-red i have array object in msg.payload.
the array object is `[{"":"This Pallet ID is already in Pick Request List"}]`

The array object has empty field name. please suggest how to retrieve value form the array.
I have tried `msg.payload[0][0]`, `msg.payload[0].Value`. But not working

Comment: did you try `msg.payload[0][""]` ?

Comment: Related, but not a dupetarget I don't think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is

```
var text = msg.payload[0][""];
```

Works in Chrome at least...